# Are all my nodes publicly available at their respective links (ie example.com/node/25)?

Tags: nodes

I'm new to Drupal and working on a pre-built Drupal site. There seems to be a large number of pages that are public with the `/node` domain path. For example, something like the link `example.com/node/10`, which appears to be publicly available so that anyone can go to it. I'm wanting to disable these nodes from being public.

I tried going to Content in the menu and then unchecking "Published" under Publishing Options. That seems to shut off the node where it appears on other pages, which is not what I want to do.

What I want to do is to prevent users from being able to access links like `example.com/node/50`, which appear to just display specific nodes isolated.

Comment: Take a look at the [Rabbit hole module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole)

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are looking for here.  If you don't want to use /node/### links, then you may want to look at the pathauto module.  This lets you create automatic 'human' URLs.  E.g. /article/[node.title]. This hides the node/### URLS.  If you are looking for how to securing nodes, then you will need to look at Drupal security model.  The basic version is the published / unpublished.  There is also a content moderation module for this.  Plus there are various other contrib modules for this as well.

Comment: I didn't know what modules were. I'll take a look at these. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rabbit Hole module addresses this very thing:

https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole

I just learned about this one a little while ago.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can try following modules:
[Rabbit hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole)
[Internal nodes](https://www.drupal.org/project/internal_nodes)
[Restrict node page view](https://www.drupal.org/project/restrict_node_view_page)

Comparison among modules:
'Rabbit Hole' apply restrictions/control on per bundle and per entity but 'Internal Nodes' and 'Restrict node page view' only control user access to page.
https://www.drupal.org/project/restrict_node_page_view/issues/1558216

A tutorial about rabbit hole:
https://www.lullabot.com/articles/module-monday-rabbit-hole